# Зависает программа при обработке 21 прерывания(TSR)

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Пишу программу, которая должна выводить в частности  имя последнего процесса(в newprogname) , попытался перехватить 21h Но программа зависает. Самостоятельно не могу разобраться :(

```
;+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Эта TSR программа при нажатии F12 выводит окно с именем последней 
; запущенной программы и количеством клавиш, нажатых во время ее выполнения 

; выгрузка:
; >имяпрог /off (например: lab2 /off)
;+--------------------------------------------------------------------------

code_seg segment
        ASSUME  CS:CODE_SEG,DS:code_seg,ES:code_seg
    org 100h
start:
    jmp begin
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int_2Fh_vector  DD  ?
old_09h         DD  ?
old_21h         DD  ?
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
flag        DB  0
high_Y      DB  07  ; координаты окна
left_X      DB  50  ; координаты окна
low_Y       DB  15  ; координаты окна
right_X     DB  75  ; координаты окна
;
page_num    DB  0
coord_Y     DB  11  ; Y координата сообщения в окне
coord_X     DB  60  ; X координата сообщения в окне
SIZES       DW  5
BUFFER      DW  0   ; сообщение выводимое в окно
String1     DB  5 dup (0)  ; Резервируем 5 байт для строки
newprogname DW ?
coordnewprog_y DB 9
coordnewprog_x DB 60
;============================================================================
new_09h proc far        ;Обработчик прерывания 09h
;
    pushf
    push    AX
    in      AL,60h      ; Введем scan-code
    cmp     AL,58h      ; Это скен-код <F12>
    je      hotkey      ; Yes

    mov AX,CS:BUFFER
    inc AX
    mov CS:BUFFER,AX

    pop     AX          ; No. Восстановим AX
    popf
    jmp     dword ptr CS:[old_09h]  ; В системный обработчик без возврата
hotkey:
    sti                 ; Не будем мешать таймеру
    in      AL,61h      ; Введем содержимое порта B
    or      AL,80h      ; Установим старший бит
    out     61h,AL      ; и вернем в порт B.
    and     AL,7Fh      ; Снова разрешим работу клавиатуры,
    out     61h,AL      ; сбросив старший бит порта B.
;
;-------------------- Вывод окна средствами BIOS ---------------------------
            push    BX  ; сохранение используемых регистров в стеке
            push    CX  ; сохранение используемых регистров в стеке
            push    DX  ; сохранение используемых регистров в стеке
            push    DS  ; сохранение используемых регистров в стеке
            ;
            push    CS  ;   настройка DS
            pop     DS  ;               на наш сегмент, т.е DS=CS
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mov     AX, 0600h      ; Задание окна
        mov     BH, 43h        ; красный по зеленому
        mov     CH, CS:high_Y     ; Ко-
        mov     CL, CS:left_X     ;    ор-
        mov     DH, CS:low_Y      ;       ди-
        mov     DL, CS:right_X    ;          наты окна
        int 10h
; ------------------------ Позиционируем курсор -----------------------------
        mov     AH,02h          ; Функция позиционирования
        mov     BH,CS:page_num  ; Видеостраница
        mov     DH,CS:coord_Y   ; Строка
        mov     DL,CS:coord_X   ; Столбец
        int 10h

        mov ax,BUFFER           ; Заносим в AX число для перевода в 10 формат
        mov cx,10               ; Задается делителем CX = 10
        mov di,SIZES            ; В di Лежит номер последнего символа строки
        dec di
Repeat:
        xor dx,dx               ; Обнуляем DX (для деления)
        div cx                  ; Делим DX:AX на CX (10),Получаем в AX частное, в DX остаток
        xchg    ax,dx           ; Меняем их местами (нас интересует остаток)
        add al,'0'              ; Получаем в AL символ десятичной цифры
        mov [String1+di],al     ; И записываем ее в строку
        xchg    ax,dx           ; Восстанавливаем AX (частное)
        dec di                  ; Уменьшаем указатель
        or  ax,ax               ; Сравниваем AX с 0
        jne Repeat              ; Если не ноль, то повторяем

; ------------------------ Вывод строки с количеством нажатых клавиш на экран -----------------------------     
    mov     CX,CS:SIZES
    mov     BX, offset  CS:String1 
    mov     AH,0Eh                 ;По одному символу
next_sym:
    mov     AL,CS:[BX]             ; Символ в AL
    inc     BX                     ; Сдвиг по строке
    cmp AL,0                       ; Не будем печатать нули, при небольшом количестве нажатий клавиш
    je @ll
    int     10h                    
    @ll:
    loop    next_sym               ; Цикл по строке

    ; ------------------------ Позиционируем курсор -----------------------------
    mov     AH,02h          ; Функция позиционирования
    mov     BH,CS:page_num  ; Видеостраница
    mov     DH,CS:coordnewprog_y   ; Строка
    mov     DL,CS:coordnewprog_x   ; Столбец
    int 10h


;------------------------- Распечатаем имя этой программы--------------------
    mov     CX,5
    mov     BX, offset  CS:newprogname 
    mov     AH,0Eh                 ;По одному символу
next_sym2:
    mov     AL,CS:[BX]             ; Символ в AL
    inc     BX                     ; Сдвиг по строке
    int     10h                    
    loop    next_sym2              ; Цикл по строке

    ; восстановление регистров из стека в порядке LIFO
    pop     DS  
    pop     DX
    pop     CX
    pop     BX
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cli
    mov     AL, 20h      ; Пошлем
    out     20h,AL       ; приказ EOI
;
    pop     AX
    popf
    iret
new_09h     endp
;===========================================================================
new_21h proc far
    pushf
    push    AX
    push    BX
    push    CX
    push    DX
    push    DS
    push    CS  ;   настройка DS
    pop     DS  ;               на наш сегмент, т.е DS=CS
    cmp AH,4Bh
    je newprog
    jmp     dword ptr CS:[old_21h]  ; В системный обработчик без возврата
    newprog:
    mov newprogname, DX 
    pop     DS  
    pop     DX
    pop     CX
    pop     BX
    pop AX
    popf
    iret 
new_21h endp
;============================================================================
int_2Fh proc far
    cmp     AH,0C7h         ; Наш номер?
    jne     Pass_2Fh        ; Нет, на выход
    cmp     AL,00h          ; Подфункция проверки на повторную установку?
    je      inst            ; Программа уже установлена
    cmp     AL,01h          ; Подфункция выгрузки?
    je      unins           ; Да, на выгрузку
    jmp     short Pass_2Fh  ; Неизвестная подфункция - на выход
inst:
    mov     AL,0FFh         ; Сообщим о невозможности повторной установки
    iret
Pass_2Fh:
    jmp dword PTR CS:[int_2Fh_vector]
;
; -------------- Проверка - возможна ли выгрузка программы из памяти ? ------
unins:
    push    BX
    push    CX
    push    DX
    push    ES
;
    mov     CX,CS   ; Пригодится для сравнения, т.к. с CS сравнивать нельзя
    mov     AX,3509h    ; Проверить вектор 09h
    int     21h ; Функция 35h в AL - номер прерывания. Возврат-вектор в ES:BX
;
    mov     DX,ES
    cmp     CX,DX
    jne     Not_remove
;
    cmp     BX, offset CS:new_09h
    jne     Not_remove
; Обработчик 21 прерывания
    mov     AX,3521h
    int     21h
;
    mov DX,ES 
    cmp CX,DX
    jne Not_remove
;
    cmp BX, offset CS:new_21h
    jne Not_remove
;

    mov     AX,352Fh    ; Проверить вектор 2Fh
    int     21h ; Функция 35h в AL - номер прерывания. Возврат-вектор в ES:BX
;
    mov     DX,ES
    cmp     CX,DX
    jne     Not_remove
;
    cmp     BX, offset CS:int_2Fh
    jne     Not_remove
; ---------------------- Выгрузка программы из памяти ---------------------
;
    push    DS
;
    lds     DX,CS:old_21h   ; Эта команда эквивалентна следующим двум
    ;mov     DX, word ptr old_21h
    ;mov     DS, word ptr old_21h+2
    mov AX, 2521h           ; Заполнение вектора старым содержимым
    int 21h
;

    lds     DX, CS:old_09h   ; Эта команда эквивалентна следующим двум
;    mov     DX, word ptr old_09h
;    mov     DS, word ptr old_09h+2
    mov     AX,2509h        ; Заполнение вектора старым содержимым
    int     21h

;   
    lds     DX, CS:int_2Fh_vector   ; Эта команда эквивалентна следующим двум
;    mov     DX, word ptr int_2Fh_vector
;    mov     DS, word ptr int_2Fh_vector+2
    mov     AX,252Fh
    int     21h
;
    pop     DS
;
    mov     ES,CS:2Ch       ; ES -> окружение
    mov     AH, 49h         ; Функция освобождения блока памяти
    int     21h
;
    mov     AX, CS
    mov     ES, AX          ; ES -> PSP выгрузим саму программу
    mov     AH, 49h         ; Функция освобождения блока памяти
    int     21h
;
    mov     AL,0Fh          ; Признак успешной выгрузки
    jmp     short pop_ret
Not_remove:
    mov     AL,0F0h          ; Признак - выгружать нельзя
pop_ret:
    pop     ES
    pop     DX
    pop     CX
    pop     BX
;
    iret
int_2Fh endp
;============================================================================
begin:
        mov CL,ES:80h       ; Длина хвоста в PSP
        cmp CL,0            ; Длина хвоста=0?
        je  check_install   ; Да, программа запущена без параметров,
                            ; попробуем установить
        xor CH,CH       ; CX=CL= длина хвоста
        cld             ; DF=0 - флаг направления вперед
        mov DI, 81h     ; ES:DI-> начало хвоста в PSP
        mov SI,offset key   ; DS:SI-> поле key
        mov AL,' '          ; Уберем пробелы из начала хвоста
repe    scasb   ; Сканируем хвост пока пробелы
                ; AL - (ES:DI) -> флаги процессора
                ; повторять пока элементы равны
        dec DI          ; DI-> на первый символ после пробелов
        mov CX, 4       ; ожидаемая длина команды
repe    cmpsb   ; Сравниваем введенный хвост с ожидаемым
                ; (DS:DI)-(ES:DI) -> флаги процессора
        jne check_install ; Неизвестная команда - попробуем установить
        inc flag_off
; Проверим, не установлена ли уже эта программа
check_install:
        mov AX,0C700h   ; AH=0C7h номер процесса C7h
                        ; AL=00h -дать статус установки процесса
        int 2Fh         ; мультиплексное прерывание
        cmp AL,0FFh
        je  already_ins ; возвращает AL=0FFh если установлена
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cmp flag_off,1
    je  xm_stranno
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov AX,352Fh                      ;   получить
                                      ;   вектор
    int 21h                           ;   прерывания  2Fh
    mov word ptr int_2Fh_vector,BX    ;   ES:BX - вектор
    mov word ptr int_2Fh_vector+2,ES  ;
;
    mov DX,offset int_2Fh           ;   получить смещение точки входа в новый
                                    ;   обработчик на DX
    mov AX,252Fh                    ;   функция установки прерывания
                                    ;   изменить вектор 2Fh
    int 21h  ; AL - номер прерыв. DS:DX - указатель программы обработки прер.
;============================================================================
    mov AX,3509h                        ;   получить
                                        ;   вектор
    int 21h                             ;   прерывания  09h
    mov word ptr old_09h,BX    ;   ES:BX - вектор
    mov word ptr old_09h+2,ES  ;
    mov DX,offset new_09h           ;   получить смещение точки входа в новый
;                                   ;   обработчик на DX
    mov AX,2509h                        ;   функция установки прерывания
                                        ;   изменить вектор 09h
    int 21h ;   AL - номер прерыв. DS:DX - указатель программы обработки прер.
;============================================================================
    mov AX,3521h                        ;   получить
                                        ;   вектор
    int 21h                             ;   прерывания  21h
    mov word ptr old_21h,BX    ;   ES:BX - вектор
    mov word ptr old_21h+2,ES  ;
    mov DX,offset new_21h           ;   получить смещение точки входа в новый
;                                   ;   обработчик на DX
    mov AX,2521h                        ;   функция установки прерывания
                                        ;   изменить вектор 09h
    int 21h ;   AL - номер прерыв. DS:DX - указатель программы обработки прер.
;============================================================================
        mov DX,offset msg1  ; Сообщение об установке
        call    print
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov DX,offset   begin           ;   оставить программу ...
    int 27h                         ;   ... резидентной и выйти
;============================================================================
already_ins:
        cmp flag_off,1      ; Запрос на выгрузку установлен?
        je  uninstall       ; Да, на выгрузку
        lea DX,msg          ; Вывод на экран сообщения: already installed!
        call    print
        int 20h
; ------------------ Выгрузка -----------------------------------------------
 uninstall:
        mov AX,0C701h  ; AH=0C7h номер процесса C7h, подфункция 01h-выгрузка
        int 2Fh             ; мультиплексное прерывание
        cmp AL,0F0h
        je  not_sucsess
        cmp AL,0Fh
        jne not_sucsess
        mov DX,offset msg2  ; Сообщение о выгрузке
        call    print
        int 20h
not_sucsess:
        mov DX,offset msg3  ; Сообщение, что выгрузка невозможна
        call    print
        int 20h
xm_stranno:
        mov DX,offset msg4  ; Сообщение, программы нет, а пользователь
        call    print       ; дает команду выгрузки
        int 20h
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
key         DB  '/off'
flag_off    DB  0
msg         DB  'already '
msg1        DB  'installed',13,10,'$'
msg4        DB  'just '
msg3        DB  'not '
msg2        DB  'uninstalled',13,10,'$'
;============================================================================
PRINT       PROC NEAR
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    RET
PRINT       ENDP
;;============================================================================
code_seg ends
         end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике 21 прерывания вы в самом начале выполняете несколько операций push, тем самым перемещая указатель стека. Сразу после этого, если вызвана не ваша функция, вы выполняете прямой переход на оригинальный обработчик. В итоге на входе в тот обработчик в стеке находятся лишние данные и он уже не может выполнить iret, так как адреса возврата на вершине стека найти не может.

Код должен выглядеть как нибудь так:

```
new_21h proc far
    pushf  ; сохраняем флаги
           ; (хотя в принципе есть вторая копия в стеке, которую туда положил int)
           ; но мы не можем знать как работает с флагами оригинальный обработчик
    cmp   AH,4Bh
    je    newprog
    popf   ; восстанавливаем флаги (которые изменял cmp)
    jmp   dword ptr CS:[old_21h]  ; В системный обработчик без возврата
newprog:
    push  DS
    ....        ;  сохранение других используемых регистров
    push  CS    ;   настройка DS
    pop   DS
    mov   newprogname, DX
    ....        ; восстановление прочих регистров
    pop   DS
    popf        ; не забываем флаги, которые сохраняли в самом начале
    iret
new_21h endp
```

Comment: Не хочу плодить много глупых вопросов, но с исправленным кодом программа не выгружается и не дает запустить другие программы(ошибки не высвечивается просто появляется пустая строка в консоли), подскажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано

Comment: @СергейБараненков На счет выгрузки не знаю. Не готов поднимать эту информацию сейчас и выяснять что там идет не так. На счет запуска новых программ ... ну вообще то тут код именно так и написан, в случае функции 4B запоминается имя, а предыдущий обработчик не вызывается. Если требуется что бы запуск работал, то конечно надо отдавать выполнение оригинальному обработчику после сохранения имени

Comment: @СергейБараненков Кстати, что значит "не выгружается" ? возвращает что нельзя выгружать или что то другое